# Doing a Http basic authentication in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm from Grails background and new to Rails. I wish to do http basic authentication in rails.

I have a code in grails which does basic authentication like this:

```
def authString = "${key}:".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
def conn = "http://something.net".toURL().openConnection()
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ${authString}")
```

Can the same be done with rails?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Write the below code, in the controller which you want to restrict using http basic authentication

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "user", :password => "password" 
end
```

Making a request with open-uri would look like this:

```
require 'open-uri'

open("http://www.your-website.net/", 
  http_basic_authentication: ["user", "password"])
```

Comment: [Curious about the downvote]. Not a good practice to write what I said?

Answer (score 22):

In Ruby on Rails 4 you can easily apply basic HTTP Authentication site wide or per controller depending on the context.

For example, if you need site wide authentication:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "hunter2"
end
```

Or on a per controller basis:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "hunter2"
end
```

Comment: hunter2? It's an older meme, but it checks out.

Answer (score 12):

I upvoted @Nishant's answer but wanted to add another tidbit. You can always set filters so it only applies to certain controller actions by passing `only` or `except` like so:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "strongpasswordhere", only: [:admin, :new, :edit, :destroy]
```

or

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "strongpasswordhere", except: [:show]
```

Very helpful in many instances.

Answer (score 8):

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  before_filter :http_basic_auth

  def http_basic_auth
    if ENV['HTTP_AUTH'] =~ %r{(.+)\:(.+)}
      unless authenticate_with_http_basic { |user, password|  user == $1 && password == $2 }
        request_http_basic_authentication
      end
    end
  end
```

and then you just need to export your environment variable with the user:password for example:

```
   export HTTP_AUTH=user:pass
```

if you are using heroku.com:

```
   heroku config:set HTTP_AUTH=user:pass
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a great Rails Cast on this topic

http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication

Answer (score 2):

When connecting to HTTP endpoints protected by basic HTTP authentication I usually use [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) is simple wrapper for lower Ruby STD classes like [net/http](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

Example usage of [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) with basic auth.

```
class Delicious
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://api.del.icio.us/v1'

  def initialize(u, p)
    @auth = {username: u, password: p}
  end

  def recent options={}
    options.merge!({basic_auth: @auth})
    self.class.get('/posts/recent', options)
  end
end

delicious = Delicious.new("<username>", "<password>")

pp delicious.recent #=> list of recent elements
```

Check for more [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are correct, but it is better to not put the user and password in the source code.

Better have the password in environment variables for production (in the code is OK for development)

```
class YourController..
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: ENV["HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_USER"], password: ENV["HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD"], if: -> { ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production' }
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "user", password: "pass", if: -> { ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != 'production' }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the latest rails version there is a `ASCIIcast` that explains with steps the **HTTP Basic Authentication**.

The link goes [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1).

**Side Note:** Be warned that HTTP Basic Authentication transmits the username and password in clear text, so you should not use this method for applications where a higher level of security is required.

Comment: If you request to a website with HTTP Basic Authentication using an `https` url the headers will still be encrypted though right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `request.basic_auth` to pass basic auth parameters required for authentication. `content_type` can be changed according to the requirement.

You will have to include -

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
```

Request code will look like this -

```
  key = "awknfkjn93013nksdkjnsd09920930jwkslkd102"
  token = "qs90si90w4jm309w0kd5009kdw700i29012dfmk"
  uri = URI("http://something.net")
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
  request.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  request.basic_auth(key, token)
  payload = {
              your_payload_key=> "your_payload_value"
            }
  request.set_form_data(payload)
  request_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https"
  }
  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, request_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end
```