# Setting the http header with basic authentication keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a site which is protected using the http basic authentication.

I wish to code a ruby snippet which allows me to pass the http basic authentication and read the contents of the web page.

I have used a way in java to send the key and other details set in HTTP header and thus read the contents of the web page. But couldn't able to find the same in ruby.

## edit:

The code I use is here:

```
   def express
    http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "dhh", :password => "secret"
   end
```

which gives me the error:

```
undefined method `http_basic_authenticate_with' for #<ServiceController:0x7f9bd73e5448>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You asked a similar question a while ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374580/doing-a-http-basic-authentication-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [it is](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html) what you are looking for:

```
 class SecretController < ApplicationController
   http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "frodo", :password => "thering"
   def index
     ...
   end
 end
```

You can also pass an exception for any particular `action`:

```
 http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "dhh", :password => "secret", :except => :index
```

There is also a [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1) about it.

**EDIT - if your version of rails is prior to 3.1, you can create your own method:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
USER, PASSWORD = 'dhh', 'secret'

before_filter :authentication_check, :except => :index

...

 private
  def authentication_check
   authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user, password|
    user == USER && password == PASSWORD
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting an erro like this :`undefined method `http_basic_authenticate_with`

Comment: Which rails version are you using?? I think this method is only available from Rails 3.1.

Comment: if you are running rais 3.2 you should be able to use the `http_basic_authenticate_with :name` method, which must be included in the `controller`. Please include the code in your question, so we can try to help you.

Comment: you have included the `http_basic_authenticate_with` inside a method and not the controller. I have edited my answer... also watch the railscasts link for more details.

Answer (score 2):

**Devise** does have built in`HTTP Basic Authentication` yet you do need to have two little things in your app to have it working :

`:database_authenticatable` strategy in your user/account model
    `config.http_authenticatable = true` in the devise initializer

Devise relies on `Warden`, which is a rack framework for authentication. On its own, `Warden` tries to provide a custom response to all unauthenticated requests, by something called failure_app, which is a valid rack app.

A simple code that performs http authentication is below:

```
def http_authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest do |user_name, password|
    user_name == "foo" && password == "bar"
  end
  warden.custom_failure! if performed?
end
```

There is also a good post on it. Check [here](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org).

One more solution(alternative) is to use a [Mechanize library](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org)

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'mechanize'
    require 'logger'

    agent = WWW::Mechanize.new { |a| a.log = Logger.new("mech.log") }
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
    agent.auth('username', 'password')
    agent.get('http://example.com') do |page|
      puts page.title
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gem such as [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty):

```
opt = {basic_auth: {username: "user123", password: "pass"}}
response = HTTParty.get("your_site", opt)
```

Comment: I'm new to rails, how do I install httparty?