# Simeple authentication for a static page with 4 digits of password

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I implemented a static page with ruby on rails that shows all the stats related to my work. I can deploy to the admin page but it requires username/pwd which is annoying. So I want a static page with simple authentication like 4 digits of codes or only some devices and access it. Any suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20794710/6163262 This is probably the quickest solution.

Comment: @whodini9 Thanks! Do you think it can verify with only password without username?

Answer (score 2):

add a basic authentication method on your `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  private

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "admin" && password == "admin"
    end
  end

end
```

Then add a `before_filter` (or `before_action` for rails5) callback on any controller you want to use this authentication.

For example, if you want to authenticate to access `reports` action from `PagesController`

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate, only: [:report]

  def about
  end

  def report
  end

end
```

Comment: Is there any other way without username? It seems that authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic method requires username.

Comment: keep the username blank if you don't want it `username == "" && password == "admin"`

Comment: yes I can leave with blank for username but I meant only password field without an username input :)

Comment: what you are asking is not possible with http basic authentication .. to do that, you need to setup a controller action and associated page with dedicated form to intake password and match the submitted password

Comment: I was hoping that http basic auth can do that haha. Thanks anyways!