# Retrieve username and password from url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to replace an old PHP server with a Rails server. There are several clients that I do not control, that authenticate by providing a username and password in the url:

```
https://user:password@example.com/update
```

How can I extract the user and password from a url in a Rails 6 application?

When I look at the url or path via the request object the user and password are stripped. The request routes correctly, I just cannot extract the credentials in order to authenticate.

## Additional detail added

I first started going down the basic auth path (even though I don't fully understand that term). I looked at some questions including [this basic auth Rails question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374580/doing-a-http-basic-authentication-in-rails). Maybe I am missing something, but the sample code does not work. If I do the following:

```
curl "http://example.com/update?foo=bar" -u "user:pass"
```

I am able to access the user and password for basic auth.
However

```
curl "http://user:pass@example.com/update?foo=bar"
```

Wait - that actually works!
I was testing the requests from Safari and the basic auth attributes were ignored and not available in my controller, but when I run the request from curl it works. Crazy.

I am going to leave this question up in case someone else encounters this specific scenario. Maybe they will see this and solve the issue.

Comment: There is nothing in the params object in the controller action?

Comment: @dbugger - no, nothing in the params

Comment: Please add your controller and route file to the question.

Comment: From the url provided, it looks to be like basic auth.
If that is the case then you can check this: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374580/doing-a-http-basic-authentication-in-rails)

Comment: If you're using Devise it has built in support for HTTP basic auth. You just need to enable it. https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication

Comment: Safari might not allow HTTP Basic auth when you're using HTTP and not HTTPS. Curl is more of a pointy tool. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/96293

Comment: you need a route defined in config/routes.rb that can match the url, with variable placeholders in place of user and password. This is a highly unusual login format!